# React Native: Animation callback does not access latest state while using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

hope you all are having a great day.
I'm new to react native animations and ran into a problem. Problem is that I'm updating the state inside Animation callback like this

```
Animated.timing(position, {
  toValue: {
    x: 500,
    y: 0,
  },
  duration: 250,
  useNativeDriver: false,
}).start(() => {
  setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1)
});
```

state is updated but when this animation function is called for the second time it does not get access to latest state. If activeIndex is 0 and it runs for first time activeIndex is updated to 1 but when this animation function is called for second time activeIndex is still 0 and it is still updated to 1 and so on. activeIndex is updated outside this callback this only happens inside the callback.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think that the problem is you are not getting and updated value for the state. Remember that setting the state is an async process and by the time you tell React to get `activeIndex` it can be stale state.

The recommended way to solve this issue is to use the callback for the `setState` function, which will get the exact previous value for that state, as follows:

```
setActiveIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying your solution is working fine but if I console.log activeIndex inside animation callback i'm still always getting 0 and not the updated one

Comment: Is just having the same behavior that I explained above